# create JSONB array grouped from column values with incrementing integers

Tags: postgresql, group-by, jsonb

For a PostgreSQL table, suppose the following data is in table `A`:

```
key_path        | key     | value
--------------------------------------
foo[1]__scrog   | scrog   | apple
foo[2]__scrog   | scrog   | orange
bar             | bar     | peach
baz[1]__biscuit | biscuit | watermelon
```

The goal is to group data when there is an incrementing number present for an otherwise identical value for column `key_path`.
For context, `key_path` is a JSON key path and `key` is the leaf key.  The desired outcome would be:

```
key_path_group                   | key     | values
------------------------------------------------------------
[foo[1]__scrog, foo[2]__scrog]   | scrog   | [apple, orange]
bar                              | bar     | peach
[baz[1]__biscuit]                | biscuit | [watermelon]
```

Also noting that for `key_path=baz[1]__biscuit` even though there is only a single incrementing value, it still triggers casting to an array of length 1.

Any tips or suggestions much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

May have answered my own question (sometimes just typing it out helps).  The following gets very close, if not exactly, what I'm looking for:

```sql
select
    regexp_replace(key_path, '(.*)\[(\d+)\](.*)', '\1[x]\3') as key_path_group,
    key,
    jsonb_agg(value) as values
from A
group by gp_key_path, key;
```